# Blank "active provider" in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, proxy

I need to set proxy settings in eclipse. For that I require to set active provider to Manual. But I am getting no option for active provider. It's blank. I am attaching a screenshot. Please help.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have the same issue.  Has anyone got an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it is related to the following bug in eclipse Mars:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479075

Adding the suggested org.eclipse.core.net.prefs file under the eclipse configuration .settings directory fixed the issue.